# The Matrix Part 4 and MySql dilemma

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do the following:

Basically I have the following design for an events table:

event:

- id
- code
- date

When a new event is created, I want to do the following:

- Check if there are any codes already available. A code is available if the date has already passed.

  `$code1 = select code from event where date_add(date, INTERVAL 7 day) < NOW() AND code NOT IN (select code from event where date_start > NOW()) limit 1`
- If a code is available, get that code and use that for the new event.

  `insert into event (code, date) VALUES($code1, NOW())`
- If a code is not available, then generate a new code.

The problem is I am afraid that when 2 events are created at the same time, they both get the same code. How can I prevent that?

The goal is to assign a code from 1-100 for each event. So because 1-100 is only 100 numbers, I need to recycle codes so that is why I check for old codes to assign to new events. I want to be able to assign codes from 1 to 100 to events by recycling old codes. I don't want to assign the same code to 2 different events.

Comment: What does this code represent logic wise? It seems like an event can easily have the same code as another because of your second step there. You are literally giving the event the code of another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ought to lock the table while you work:

```
LOCK TABLE event WRITE;
SELECT MIN(code) FROM event WHERE date_add(date_end, INTERVAL 7 day) < NOW()
     AND code NOT IN (SELECT code FROM event WHERE date_start > NOW());
...
INSERT INTO event ...
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

You might also keep a table with all active codes (in this case all numbers from 1 to 100). In this case you can do the `INSERT` with a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO event ( code, <other fields> )
    SELECT MIN(codes.code) AS code, <other values> FROM codes
        LEFT JOIN event ON ( codes.code = event code
        AND ( event.date_end > DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 7 day)
              OR event.date_start >= NOW()) )
    WHERE event.code IS NULL;
```

This selects all codes that are not used in "active" events, and inserts the smallest of them into `event` (add other fields as needed).

You could also employ a subSELECT ( `SELECT DISTINCT code FROM event` ) in place of the `codes` table, but in that case you would only select codes that you already used at least once; any "new" codes would be ignored.

A side effect of the above logic is that larger codes gets reused less often, i.e., if you have twenty active events, chances are that they're using codes from 1 to 20. If you instead want to recycle codes evenly, you can for example `SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`.

Comment: If the insert is an update state instead how can I change the insert code you have to an update statement code? like UPDATE event SET ...

Comment: UPDATE? But you were *creating* an event... Maybe you need to clarify your question and supply a full example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a long shot, and I'm not a database person, so take my suggestion with a grain of salt and do your own research ...

I think what you want is serializable transactions. Basically, you first ask MySQL to make [transaction isolation serializable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html) using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`. Then, before your three steps, you begin a transaction by running `START TRANSACTION`, and after your three steps you run `COMMIT`.

Some further reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html

I am not sure about the overhead the serializability incurs. Hopefully someone more familiar with databases can chip in.

If you can work around your problem, I'd personally rather do that than using transactions.